# Cut in the sidewalk of my tyre

Tags: tires, jeep, sidewall-damage

I was driving at very low speed in a campsite, I turned too early around a corner and hit my inside rear tyre on a rock. Turns out the rock was sharp and slashed a small part of the tyre wall (about .3cm in depth) and I’m wondering if I should worry. My car is FWD and I am halfway through a trip around Europe (~600 miles left), no spare tyre, only a repair kit as is normal these days. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have a spare and a means to change it? If so, I wouldn't worry about it too much. You should be able to drive it. If something happens, you can always change it out.

Comment: No spare unfortunately, just a tyre repair kit :/

Comment: I really don't think you'll have any issues with it. If you do have an issue, I doubt the tire repair kit will do much for you, though. The gash is really not that deep. If it's holding air and you don't see cords, I don't think there'll be an issue.

Comment: Okay thank-you very much for answering quickly. Based on your words, I think I will be fine to get home. I’ll just keep an eye on it I guess. I am covered in the EU with my insurance so I could call for assistance but if gonna think it will be okay then I won’t waste their time :)